# ASP.NET session dying?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 app running on AWS Free Tier. The problem I have is that the session keeps dying.

I have included the following in System.Web:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="720" />
```

I backed that statement up with a Javascript "Session Bump" method in the Masterpage as well, which executes every 10 minutes:

```
var sessionBump = setInterval(bumpSession, 600000);
    function bumpSession() {
        $.get("/admin/secure/ajax/keepalive.aspx", function (data) {
            // do nothing, just keep the session alive
        });
    }
```

When testing last night, the session was still alive after about 2-2.5 hours, however when I left the app overnight (well, 6 hours) then the session had died. Why won't it stay alive? I need it alive as the app is used sporadically by users over 12 hour shifts.

Regards,

Bob

Comment: Was your clientside still awake during last 6h?

Comment: Are there any error logs on the server side?

Comment: @PhongVo seemed like it. Screen had gone to sleep, but my Mac was still awake.

Comment: @isim in all honesty, not sure where they store the log on EC2 machines? Would I need to connect or are they readily available in the UI? What type of entry would I be looking for?

Comment: On the EC2 console, right-click on your instance, and select `Get System Log`

Comment: Move the session from InProc, to an SQL server. InProc can be recycle at any time, and there you lose your session data.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ResolveUrl:

```
function KeepSessionAlive() 
{
    $.get(ResolveUrl('~/KeepSessionAlive.ashx'), function (data) { });
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(KeepSessionAlive, 300000); //5 minutes (call before session timeout - if timeout= 6)
});


function ResolveUrl(url)
{
    if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) 
    {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}
```

//Or include in master page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
    function ResolveUrl(url) {
        if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) {
            url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
        }
        return url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but why do I need to use resolve url? Shouldn't a regular post to the page do the trick? Just curious.

Comment: ResoleURL to get relative path of KeepSessionAlive.ashx. Unless you stay at home page, you can't call KeepSessionAlive.ashx

(Sorry for my bad E)